# Make HTML5 input type="number" accepting dashes

Tags: html, mobile, input, keyboard

I want to use the number input type for my HTML form.

Unfortunately it only accepts real numbers, no dashes  between.

Is there a way to make the number input accepting numbers like "1234-123456789" ?

Comment: Values for `number` inputs must always be valid floating point numbers and therefor may only contain a single dash (that is, a minus sign) in front of the number. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-floating-point-number

Answer (score 21):

I recently had the same issue. I got around it by using type="tel" instead of type="text" or type="number". By using 'tel' I was able to get a numeric only keyboard on mobile devices and still be able to use my pattern="[0-9\-]+".

Here is the code I used. I hope this is good enough for what you need. They really need to make it so that adding a pattern attribute overrides any built in pattern set by the type attribute.

```
<input id='zipcode' name='zipcode' type='tel' pattern="[0-9\-]+" placeholder='Zip-code'>
```

Of course this will only work if all you want is dashes and possibly parentheses.

Comment: Won't this cause issues with accessibility? Will screen readers tell people to enter a phone number?

Comment: @Carlin: Good point. This very well might cause an issue with screen readers. As such it isn't a perfect solution, but it's up to the developer as to whether that is an acceptable sacrifice.

Comment: Thanks for this, clever little hack. A note: This also seems to allow '/', another character not allowed in number inputs. Using this to get date inputs that use mobile number keypad.

Comment: I am sorry for using this comment only to thank you very much for this clever solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Works for Android but not for iPhone (no middle dash button appears)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular expression against which the value will be validated. Simply put it in the `pattern` attribute. You also have to change your input's `type` to `text` in order to use that.

```
 <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+([-\,][0-9]+)?" name="my-num"
               title="The number input must start with a number and use either dash or a comma."/>
```

Comment: Already tried that. But then I loose the nice number keyboard on mobile devices.

Answer (score 4):

inputmode="numeric" is your new best friend..

https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-inputmode/#numeric

Comment: New since 2019 for major browser. Since 2012 in mobile Firefox. Still (2023) not supported in desktop Safari. https://caniuse.com/input-inputmode