# Input type="number" accepts dashes -- HTML

Tags: html

I've got:

```
<td><input type="number" min="0" style="width: 3em" data-bind="value: $data.qty" /></td>
```

Which accepts '-56' as number. I'd like to completely disable any other character other than numbers.

I've seen a post ([Make HTML5 input type=“number” accepting dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043340/make-html5-input-type-number-accepting-dashes)) which is completely the opposite of what I want.

Which kind of input type should I use, instead of having to write patterns etc?

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'></input>
```

HTML 5:

```
<input type = "number">
```